# iPhone Application in spanish using foreign characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, character-encoding

I'm making an iphone application using some Spanish characters. All of these characters are being included on a various text files. The matter is that when I import the data using NSMutableArrays or NSData objects, all the special characters was replaced for strange symbols. I try to solve this problem using for all text files UTF-8 enconder but no changes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip. I solved the problem. When we're working with spanish characters we need to implement the serializable object with the following method of NSString class:

(id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error

You'll need to pass "enc". I used "4" and working for me. Regards.
Cesar.

Comment: 4 is equivalent to `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, by the way, which you should use instead of its literal value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using different encodings—using UTF-8 will only work if the text is actually in that encoding, which it apparently isn't. For example, try ISO Latin-1 or MacRoman.